# Console.log('Dynamic page') logging twice in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I added `Console.log('Dynamic page')` in a dynamic page in NextJs, but I realise it logs twice instead of once. I moved the log function into useEffect with an empty array dependency but it still logged twice. What could be the issue here? Thank you

The code /topics/[articleId].js:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect } from "react"
import Image from "next/image"
import Link from "next/link"
import ExcitedSVG from '../../../components/reaction-icons/excited'
import HappySVG from '../../../components/reaction-icons/happy'
import InLoveSVG from '../../../components/reaction-icons/in-love'
import NotSureSVG from '../../../components/reaction-icons/not-sure'
import SillySVG from '../../../components/reaction-icons/silly'
import ArticleStyles from "../../../components/styles/article.module.css"

export default function Article(){

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('Log once'); <--- //It logs twice instead
    },[])

    return (
        <div className={`${ArticleStyles.articlePg} pt-5`}>
            Component content            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Show the code...

Comment: If you have something that triggers a re-render like another hook, a state updating, updating props from a parent components, etc then yeah it will re-render and logout twice.
Without the code its unclear exactly why.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Post updated to include code. I am currently working in localhost

Comment: @Lith Post updated to include code. I am currently working in localhost

Comment: Needs more detail. How is `Article` being mounted? Is there only 1 `Article` on the page? If so, are you sure the parent component isn't being re-rendered?

Comment: @cSharp Yes there is only one Article on the page (single article details page), which shows up when a user clicks on an article with the url that follows the following dynamic route:  /topics/[articleId].js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the main reason for double rendering is because of [`StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) in React (only in development mode). You can remove it in [`next.config.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/react-strict-mode)

```
module.exports = {
  //reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

Comment: tnx but why is this happening?

Comment: I have the answer for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047304/useeffect-function-fetch-multiple-data/72047454#72047454), you can check it out, @MohmmadEbrahimiAval