# useeffect function fetch multiple data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to fetch data from an API from an input. After providing the input and calling the data, I am getting two fetch call from same data. here is the code of input:

```
  const [countryName, setCountryName] = useState<string>("");

  const handleInputChange = (event: {
    target: { value: React.SetStateAction<string> };
  }) => {
    setCountryName(event.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    navigate(`/country/${countryName}`);
  };

<TextField
          variant="standard"
          placeholder="Enter country Name"
          value={countryName}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
```

Here I am using the input to fetch the data:

```
const { name } = useParams();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const [country, setCountry] = useState<InitCountry>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountry = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      const response = await fetch(
        `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${name}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      setCountry(data.length > 1 ? data[2] : data[0]);

      setLoading(false);
    };
    getCountry();
  }, [name]);
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup seems good, but the root cause is possibly from [`React.StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions: ...

This effect is only in development which means it won't happen in your production, but if you don't want *intentionally double-invoking*, you can remove it from your code.