# Why Next.js code lifecycle executes several times?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lifecycle

I've recently started learning Next.js and I've been faced with something strange. I have this simple code:

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/Router';
import {Profile} from '../../components/Profile';

const JobsListingPage = () => {
    const Router = useRouter();
    console.log(Router.query);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Job Listing Dynamic Page</h1>
            <Profile />
        </div>
    );
}

export default JobsListingPage;
```

It works well and I get the result in the console. **The strange part is, this code gets executed 4 times on the client side.** Why really? Two first time it's empty and two last times it contains the data. Is that normal or I'm doing something wrong?

[image]

Doesn't look like a normal lifecycle.

Comment: the first `{}` is for the initial rendering for hydrating React on the client-side. `{slug}` logs and onwards are populating states for re-renderings. If you want to disable double invoking (causing 2 similar logs), you should check `StrictMode` in [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905418/console-logdynamic-page-logging-twice-in-nextjs/71907321#71907321). If you find how to turn `StrictMode` off in Next.js, I have a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905418/console-logdynamic-page-logging-twice-in-nextjs/71907321#71907321).

Comment: Thank you!~~ Glad that I'm able to help :D

Answer (score 1):

Adding a console in root level is not a good way to measure the component rendering cycles.

wrap this inside a useEffect and check whether it's still duplicating.

```
 const {query} = useRouter();  

 useEffect(() => {console.log(query)}, [query])
```

if this is only printing 2 consoles (first one empty) then component rendering fine

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined`

Comment: update console log console.log(query) @MartinAJ

Comment: Yeah, better https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px4Y9.png, thanks, upvoted

Comment: try using react.memo https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: I did it like this `export default React.memo(JobsListingPage);`. Still 3 times.