# Function Exported by Next.js middleware.ts not Triggered

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

Regarding the following code (a StackBlitz version can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webcodingcenter-nextjs-10?file=app%2Fmiddleware.ts)), why wasn't the function exported by the Next.js middleware.ts file triggered when I accessed https://[domain]/dashboard/profile ?

/app/middleware.ts:

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server';
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
   console.log('--> middleware.tsx');
   return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url));
}
```

/app/dashboard/profile/page.tsx:

```
export default async function Profile() {
   console.log('--> page.tsx');
   let v = (
      await (
         await fetch(
           'https://webcodingcenter1gkq8ip-biih--3000--810981ba.local-credentialless.webcontainer.io/dashboard'
         )
      ).json()
   ).visits;
  return <h1>{v}</h1>;
}
```

/app/dashboard/route.tsx:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
var visits = 1;
export async function GET(request: Request) {
   console.log('--> route.tsx');
   visits++;
   return NextResponse.json({ visits });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because you are putting the `middleware.ts` inside the `app` folder, it has to be either in the root or if you are using a `src` folder you can place it inside it.

[From Next.js official docs:](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#convention)

> Use the file middleware.ts (or .js) in the root of your project to
> define Middleware. For example, at the same level as pages or app, or
> inside src if applicable.

Check the updated [stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webcodingcenter-nextjs-10-ajvok8?file=middleware.ts)

Comment: Ah, tx! Interestingly, it is triggered several times at each request.

Comment: It's a normal behavior related to **React strict mode**. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71907321/7918037), furthermore you could search _"react console log multiple times"_